# How do I access the dataProvider directly in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, dataprovider

How do I access the dataProvider directly in react-admin? I tried to use a **custom** **dataProvider** but I do not know how to use it. My goal is to show a list in the output using the map.

//Contacts.js

```
/// --- List ---
export const ContactList = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {data} = useGetList('contacts', props.id);
  return (
     <List className={classes.list}>
      {data.map(({id, name, person}) => (
        <React.Fragment key={id}>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Avatar alt="Profile Picture" src={person}/>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText primary={name}/>
          </ListItem>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </List>
  )
};
```

//App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={MyLayout}>
    <Resource
      name="contacts"
      list={ContactList}
      show={ShowContact}
      edit={EditGuesser}
      create={CreateContact}
      icon={ContactPhoneIcon}/>
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

//DataProvider.js

```
import fakeDataProvider from 'ra-data-fakerest';

const dataProvider = fakeDataProvider({
  contacts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Tom",
      numbers: {number: '09367371111', type: 'Mobile'},
      person: '/static/images/avatar/5.jpg',

    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Sara",
      numbers: {number: '0936737999', type: 'Home'},
      person: '/static/images/avatar/1.jpg',
    },
  ],
});

export default dataProvider;
```

Console.log
[image: Console.log]

Comment: Look at here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#using-a-custom-iterator

Comment: But your code looks completely ok. Which part is not working as expected and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @KiaKaha  dataProvider has data but I can not access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a custom list renderer, alternative to `<Datagrid>`, and pass it as child of `<List>`:

```
export const ContactList = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
     <List className={classes.list}>
        <ContactSimpleList /<
    </List>
  )
};
```

The `<List>` component creates a `ListContext`, and places the `ids`, `data` and `total` in it. So you can access this data through the context in the list renderer:

```
import { useListContext } from 'react-admin';

const ContactSimpleList = () => {
  const { ids, data } = useListContext();
  return (
    <>
      {ids.map(id => (
          <ListItem key={id} button>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Avatar alt="Profile Picture" src={data[id].person}/>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText primary={data[id].name}/>
          </ListItem>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, the SimpleList you're trying to render looks a lot like a native component provide by react-admin: [the `<SimpleList>` component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-simplelist-component). You probably don't need to write  custom renderer.